# How to Invert boolean 'false' in typescript (ionic3 and cordova)

Tags: android, angular, cordova, typescript, ionic3

I'm having a somewhat unexpected problem with inverting booleans in my application.

**Environment:**
I'm having an application, written in typescript with Ionic 3 and I deploy it with help of cordova on an android device.

- Android API 25
- Cordova version: 7.0.1
- "@angular/core": "4.1.0"
- "ionic-angular": "3.2.1"
- "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "^1.2.1"
- Typescript 2.3.3

**Problem:**
I'm simply trying to invert a boolean, like shown in the console.log example below:

```
console.log('Clazz: ', clazz.name, ' : ', clazz.boolValue, ' : ', !clazz.boolValue)
```

Output:

```
Clazz:  A  :  true  :  false
Clazz:  B  :  true  :  false
Clazz:  C  :  true  :  false
Clazz:  D  :  false  :  false
Clazz:  E  :  false  :  false
Clazz:  F  :  false  :  false
```

So, 'true' gets inverted, but 'false' remains the same value. And with that my *ngIf-Directives in Angular do not work as expected.

**Question:**
Am I doing something completly wrong? Or did it just happen, that the combined software versions I'm using do have a glitch together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess but it's probably a decent one, I think your `clazz.boolValue` might somehow be a string rather than a boolean at runtime. This would describe the behavior you're seeing.

```
!'true' // evaluates to boolean value false
!'false' // also evaluates to boolean value false
```

Try

```
console.log('Clazz: ', clazz.name, ' : ', clazz.boolValue, '|', typeof clazz.boolValue, ' : ', !clazz.boolValue)
```

to confirm.

Comment: Thank you very much. Even though the value was defined with "boolValue: boolean", that definition no longer holds true, where this code is executed.

Comment: Yep. it's going to be especially important with typescript to sanitize your inputs as early as possible since type checking doesn't happen at runtime